# Inno setup: Read and write internal Files at runtime

Tags: unity-game-engine, inno-setup, software-distribution

I'm pretty new with Inno Setup and I am searching a way to use it with my app.

I wrote my Windows app with Unity3D (that exports it in many files and folders) but I need a single executable file to distribute it.

If I use inno setup ignoring the generation of textfiles runtime, everything is ok. 
But my app has to generate and read some textFiles to manage some features and, if I use Inno Setup with this feature, these files are ignored and my app doesn't work.

I know that I have to tell Inno how and where manage these files in its script but I have no idea how to do that

I hope that my question should be understandable and that someone of you wanna spend some of their time to help me

Many thanks to the community

J.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by *”inno setup ignoring the generation of textfiles runtime”*.

Comment: Thanks Martin for your interesting. My app creates a textFiles with the scores of the player and save it in the Application main directory. These files must be writable and readable during the game. The app is written in C# and,  to manage this aspect, I have imported System.IO to use File.ReadAllLines, File.Exists, File.Delete or File.AppendAllText. If I export the app from unity and run it, everything is ok, but if I use Inno Setup to create the .exe executable file, the app doesn't read or write any files. In my opinion the problem is that it doesn't find Application.dataPath. Thanks again

Comment: You were right, Martin. My problem was related to permissions! I've solved my problem following the link you suggested. Thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome. Once you obtain upvote privilege (15 reputation), please consider upvoting my answer.